# Vector going towards (0,0) in p5js

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm currently trying to create a 2d game where 'zombies' chase after the player and the scene moves around in p5j . My problem is that the zombie makes a beeline for point (0,0) and then rotates around it, effectively staying there.

I created a test project where the zombie follows the mouse. It worked with almost the same code, and I can't figure out what the difference was.

Here's a stack snippet using some code from my original project. If anyone could help me solve this bug it would be great. It contains the same bug. The code which concerns the zombie is under the class ZombieHandler

```js
winX = 666
winY = 400
//If you are looking through this for the issue go down to the class ZombieHandler
function setup() {
  createCanvas(winX, winY);
  background(150);
  angleMode(DEGREES)
  rectMode(CENTER)
}
class User {
  constructor(x, y, rotation, speed, rotspeed) {
    this.posX = x;
    this.posY = y;
    this.rotation = rotation;
    this.speed = speed;
    this.size = 30;
    this.rotspeed = 0;
  }
  render() {
    translate(winX / 2, winY / 2);
    rotate(this.rotation);
    translate(-winX / 2, -winY / 2);
    fill(70);
    rect(winX / 2 + this.size / 2, winY / 2, this.size, this.size / 2, 5, 5, 5, 5);
    fill(0);
    rect(winX / 2, winY / 2, this.size, this.size, 5, 5, 5, 5);
    translate(winX / 2, winY / 2);
    rotate(-this.rotation);
    translate(-winX / 2, -winY / 2);
  }
  control(cameraX, cameraY) {
    this.rotation += this.rotspeed;
    let pos = createVector(this.speed, 0)
    pos.rotate(this.rotation)
    console.log("Player.posX: " + this.posX.toString())
    console.log("Player.posY: " + this.posY.toString())
    //set x to left if past right, and vice versa
    //update pos
    if (this.posX - pos.x < 2295 && this.posX - pos.x > -1630) {
      this.posX -= pos.x;
      cameraX -= pos.x;
    }
    if (this.posY - pos.y < 860 && this.posY - pos.y > -1065) {
      this.posY -= pos.y;
      cameraY -= pos.y
    }
    //speed decay
    this.speed *= 0.91;
    if (this.speed < 0.5 && this.speed > 0 || this.speed > 0.5 && this.speed < 0) {
      this.speed = 0;
    }
    //rot decay
    this.rotspeed *= 0.95;
    if (this.rotspeed > 0) {
      this.rotspeed -= 0.5
    } else if (this.rotspeed < 0) {
      this.rotspeed += 0.5
    }
    return [cameraX, cameraY]
  }
}
class ZombieHandler {
  constructor(list) {
    this.list = list;
  }
  render(Player) {
    //zombie list format [[x,y,speed],[x,y,speed]]
    this.list.forEach(zombie => {
      var x = zombie[0] - Player.posX;
      var y = zombie[1] - Player.posY;
      var hyp = Math.hypot(x, y)
      var point = Math.acos(x / hyp) * (180 / Math.PI)
      fill(0)
      rect(zombie[0] + Player.posX + winX / 2, zombie[1] + Player.posY + winY / 2, 30, 30, 5, 5, 5, 5)
    });
  }
  control(Player) {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.list.length; i++) {
      let angle = Math.atan2(Player.posY - this.list[i][1], Player.posX - this.list[i][0]);
      if (angle < 0) {
        angle += Math.PI * 2
      }
      // at this point the zombie is attempting to rotate between angles 145 and -35 around 0, leaving it trapped in a loop
      this.list[i][0] += this.list[i][2] * Math.cos(angle);
      this.list[i][1] += this.list[i][2] * Math.sin(angle);
    }
  }
}
Player = new User(50, 50, 0, 0, 0)
Zombie = new ZombieHandler([])
var inputchecker = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
var tick = 0
var zombie_timer = 0
var cameraX = 0
var cameraY = 0

function draw() {
  background(150)
  noStroke()
  //Input Handler
  document.onkeydown = (e) => { //inputlist input checker
    e = e || window.event;
    if (e.key === "ArrowUp") {
      inputchecker[0] = 1;
    } else if (e.key === "ArrowLeft") {
      inputchecker[1] = 1;
    } else if (e.key === "ArrowRight") {
      inputchecker[2] = 1;
    } else if (e.key === "ArrowDown") {
      inputchecker[3] = 1;
    }
  };
  document.onkeyup = (e) => { //inputlist input checker
    e = e || window.event;
    if (e.key === "ArrowUp") {
      inputchecker[0] = 0;
    } else if (e.key === "ArrowLeft") {
      inputchecker[1] = 0;
    } else if (e.key === "ArrowRight") {
      inputchecker[2] = 0;
    } else if (e.key === "ArrowDown") {
      inputchecker[3] = 0;
    }
  };
  if (tick == 4) {
    if (inputchecker[0] == 1) {
      Player.speed += 3
    } else if (inputchecker[3] == 1) {
      Player.speed -= 2
    }
    if (inputchecker[1] == 1) {
      Player.rotspeed -= 2.5;
    } else if (inputchecker[2] == 1) {
      Player.rotspeed += 2.5;
    }
    tick = 0
  };
  //Function Call
  var camera = Player.control(cameraX, cameraY)
  cameraX = parseInt(camera[0])
  cameraY = parseInt(camera[1])


  if (zombie_timer == 50) {
    //add zombie creation code here
    //distance 1000
    //create a 0-359 random number generator for angle
    //zombie list format [[x,y,speed],[x,y,speed]]
    let pos = createVector(200, 0)
    pos.rotate(Math.floor(Math.random() * 360))
    Zombie.list.push([cameraX + pos.x, cameraY + pos.y, 3])
  }
  Zombie.control(Player)
  Player.render()
  Zombie.render(Player)
  zombie_timer += 1;
  tick += 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.6.0/lib/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please don't delete and ask the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77353234/vector-movement-going-to-point-0-0-in-javascript

Comment: @jabaa Alright sorry

Comment: Although I did update it, and while it probably is possible to answer now, the probability of that one getting unclosed was almost nil. The reason it got closed was because it had no stack snippet, and this one does.

Comment: If you'd have done @ggorlen, I'd have voted to reopen and it'd be put in the reopen queue and would likely have been taken care of. Although reposting isn't ideal, at least it looks good now though (maybe not _totally_ minimal, but I'll take it), thanks.

Comment: In any case, the zombie goes to 0, 0 because that's where the player is, right?

Comment: @ggorlen even if you move the player before the zombie spawns, the zombie goes to 0,0. the scene is larger than the screen and that player will always be rendered in the center. Also, when the player moves, the zombie should take the updated position and move towards the player. It does seem to recieve the updated position in the zombie.control() function, but the rotation never is never accurate to it, staying around 0,0

Comment: Got it, that makes sense.

Comment: I changed the player starting position to 50, 50. the issue still occurs

Comment: Stack Overflow is a question and answer platform for specific questions. Do you have a specific question? [“I wrote some buggy code that I can’t fix” is not a question, it’s a story, and not even an interesting story.](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)  Can you debug the code, isolate the problem and create [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

I think the bug lies within the rendering/display code rather than the `control(...)` function moving the Zombies towards the player.

Take another look at your `rect(...)` call in `ZombieHandler.render(Player)`; I think you're mistakenly adding the zombie coords to the player's rather than computing the difference between them.

This codepen makes that one small tweak and it seems to have the zombies move towards the player: https://codepen.io/lecrte/pen/PoVmrzV?editors=0010

---

Separately, you might want to looking into flocking code, eg: https://p5js.org/examples/simulate-flocking.html ... so the zombies don't stack on top of each other.

And you can move those `document.onkeydown` and `document.onkeyup` outside of your draw() function, since they only need to be set up once; Minor additional overhead to set up the key listeners every frame. (There as https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/keyPressed and a similar for keyReleased which you can look into)